# Azure user Email field not populated on sign-up with custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When an user sign-up, I would like to have the "Email" field in the "Contact info" section in Azure to be populated by the email the user entered for sign-up.

This is my policy:

```
 <ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <!--Local account sign-up page-->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">You are not approved. Contact your administrator for approval.</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">none</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertIsApproved" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-AssertIsApproved">
      <DisplayName>Assert Email Verified Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertIsApproved" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>

<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <!-- Write data during a local account sign-up flow. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
      <!-- Transform claims (given name, surname) to proper display name -->
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altitude3Id" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isAvivaBroker" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_avivaAvantageId" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />          
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Write data during edit profile flow. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId">
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
      </PersistedClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Read data after user authenticates with a local account. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altitude3Id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isAvivaBroker" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_avivaAvantageId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <!-- Read data after user authenticates with a federated account. -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altitude3Id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isAvivaBroker" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_avivaAvantageId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

I'm using the basic SignUpOrSignIn UserJourney if that's of any relevance.

This is the field I would like to be populated:
[Contact Info.Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VjUi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the below line in the Persist Claim:

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="mail" />
```

Comment: This works great! I was trying to do `<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />` but this was not letting me create an user with error: "Unable to retrieve information". Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yes actually when we persist we map with the User attribute. For eg:- **email** value storing to **signInNames.emailAddress** attribute, **email** value to **mail** attribute, etc.

Comment: I've posted a new question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197327/is-there-a-way-to-validate-custom-attribute-in-ropc-flow-before-sending-tokens
Still for custom policies. Would be great if you have some time.