# Is there a way to validate custom attribute in ROPC Flow before sending tokens?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

All users have a user attribute "extension_isApproved". They can only log in or receive token when it is set to True. However, I can't figure out how to do this in a ROPC Flow. The behavior I want is to send back an error message if the user asking the tokens is not approved.

I started from the base template found at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-ropc/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

There is my code (I've already tried some things to restrict the user but it doesn't work):

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials-OAUTH2">
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">You are not approved. Contact your administrator for approval.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">We can't seem to find your account</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfInvalidPassword">Your password is incorrect</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfOldPasswordUsed">Looks like you used an old password</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="logonIdentifier" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Username}"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" DefaultValue="{OIDC:Password}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />

        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{Settings:ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="{Settings:IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertIsApproved" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

---

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Session Management</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-RefreshTokenReadAndSetup">
      <DisplayName>Trustframework Policy Engine Refresh Token Setup Technical Profile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="None" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-AssertIsApproved" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

---

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertIsApproved" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
    </InputParameters>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

The rest of the code is the same as the base template for what touches the ROPC Flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what we did is to add `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />`  in the technical profile `ROPC_Auth.xml`.

By doing that, you will receive the custom attribute directly in the `id_token` of the response when you call your ROPC flow.

We contacted Microsoft Support and they told us that the way we wanted to do it at first (by blocking the user and returning an error) was too advanced for them and they don't know how to do it or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**ROPC** doesn’t work when there is any interruption to the authentication flow that needs user interaction.For example, when a password has expired or needs to be changed, multi-factor authentication is required, or when more information needs to be collected during sign-in (for example, user consent).
Refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: Thanks again Rohit for your time. However, it doesn't any user interaction. It only needs to verify a custom attribute (if set to true or false) and then decide to refuse or accept to send a token. From this, I don't know where you see a user interaction.

Comment: Only self-asserted technical profiles can use validation technical profiles.
**AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue** Transformation can only run when it use as Validation Technical Profile. 

Scenarios I tried:(I tried just to implement the policy, not integration with app) 


1. Step 4 of this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141778/how-to-make-user-return-on-login-page-after-sign-up-in-azure-ad-b2c. The only issue is it will give status code 200 but not share the tokens. 

2. You can disable the account during SignUp (accountEnabled=false). Give error_denied with 400 code.

Comment: Ok I understand. Since it is not possible, I would like to return the "extension_isApproved" in the body with the tokens so that the verification can be done on the other side. Is there a way for this?

Comment: I found how to put the "isApproved" in the id_token. But is there a way to send it directly in the body and not in the token?

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: At first, I was trying to return an error when the user is not approved. When you told me it is not possible, what I did is, even if the user is not approved, I'm sending a token and all the information, but I put in the body of the request an "isApproved" field saying if he is approved. To this point, it will be to the other party to verify with this field if it should give the token to the user or not.